ArcGIS Pro - unable to autoenable attachments for ArcGIS Online feature-hosted layer
I want to enable attachments once my ArcGIS Pro layer is published as the feature-hosted. Unfortunately, the selected options in the Configuration panel don't work as expected.


After uploading the layer attachments aren't still available.
Is there any way of fixing it?

Which of your in the first screenshot provided options should to the job? I dont see any option in arcgis-pro to automatically set "Enable Attachmets". I guess thats something that can be done only after sharing the weblayer.
